# Normal temperature for an i5 4670?

Tags: cpu, temperature, intel-core-i5

I've got an i5 4670, and according to HWMonitor the temperatures are around 70-80°C when not much is going on and sometimes go up to 90-100. This is too much for my CPU, isn't it? Can it be a problem with HWMonitor, or with the sensors? Otherwise, what should I do?

Comment: My i5 processor's temperature is at about 35-50°C when not overclocking. Even with heavy gaming and graphics you should get below 80°C.

Comment: What do you think I should do then?

Comment: Use Intel's own test software if you want to know for sure what's up with your CPU: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792

Answer (score 1):

Unless, you have Apple MacBookPro...your CPU temp is too high !!!

Idle Apple MacBookPro 2016 with i5 has got about 60deg C, flat out 100deg C...then comes HW throttling.

My Apple MBP 2011 used to run same temps

My server with Intel Pentium G4400 (with Intel OEM cooler) has got idle 29deg and full load 35deg C

Comment: I don't, it's a desktop computer. Any advice?

Comment: open case, check out for dust; replace thermal paste between heatsink and CPU; optimise flow throughout case

Answer (score 1):

My 4670k is 35°C (33°C cores) measured with open hardware monitor by writing this. According to Intel your T case is ~72°C, so these 80°C temperatures are not possible with your CPU I think. There is a 30°C difference from idle to 100% usage according to your text, which should be ok with an average sink. Try using another software, aida64 is the best to measure this. It can be sensor failure or wrong CPU microcode in the BIOS, wrong Tjmax settings in the HWMonitor, etc. Updating BIOS (motherboard firmware) might help.

Just to be sure open the case and check whether the heatsink fan is running. Check whether the heatsink is really hot. If it isn't hot by high CPU load, then it does not cool properly. You can try reapplying thermal paste, but I don't think it will help.

after 2 years:

There are 2 possible explanations.

- Your CPU temperature sensor does not work properly.
- AIDA64 and HWMonitor uses wrong scale for the sensor, so it counts with a 100°C max instead of a 80°C max. In this case the real value should be 80/100*80 = 64°C. As far as I remember it is possible to change the scale in AIDA64 settings or maybe with right click on the value. I had to do this only once 5-10 years ago. I am not sure how to get info about the temperature sensor scale.

Comment: I downloaded aida64 and it says the same thing. But if it was actually at that temperature, wouldn't it die?

Comment: @Nico It can't be on that temp. It would throttle over 70°C.